# Group on page count

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report which is grouped on an `ID` field. Each grouping is roughly 1-3 pages depending on how much data Is pulled from the source.

Is there a way to group the report based on the page count of each section?

**Example:**

- All Groups that are 3 pages
- All Groups that are 2 pages
- All Groups that are 1 page

Comment: Do you want to sort the groups by size?

Comment: Preferably seperate files, but a sort will work in the mean time. I just cant get the grouping on the page count or even produce the right number. I only get the entire ID field count.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not access the number of pages since the grouping is done before the render of the page.

But, assuming you have a table T with a column ID being of a set of values v, which you group by, why not do a count of how many rows there are per value v and join that to you report source (or just use the HAVING clause)? You can maybe derive the number of pages by the number of members of each ID.

Like

```
ID value count

1    a     2
2    a     2
3    b     1
...
```

Comment: Hi Rolan, thank you for your reply. I was able to get the grouping done through a different method. I did notice that paging was done dynamically so grouping through it was more trouble then it was worth.